# iPhone : UITableView on top of another : reveals the below table

Tags: iphone, ios

In my iphone app, am having a menu which is a UITableView, which has 13 rows, like this

[image]

In choice 'G', am showing another menu (which is again another UITableViewController) by adding this submenu as a subview of the main menu like this :

[image]

Everything seems okay until you scroll the submenu up and down few times. Then the main menu (which has 13 items) below the sub-menu (which has 9 items) starts showing up underneath the sub-menu like this

[image]

it becomes messy. How do I avoid this? I have defined 'numberOfRowsInSection' method in both the main & submenu, but it scrolls in an ugly manner to reveal the main menu below it, when it shouldn't (having been added as a submenu set to the frame size of the main menu when adding).

Can someone please help?

Comment: Why do you have 2 table views on top of each other, if the user taps G shouldn't you transition the user to another view such as how the detail view flow works?

Comment: @Nick, other options take to a detailed view, whereas option 'G' has to reveal a submenu

Comment: Right, I get that, what I'm saying is that you transition to the new view controller in a detail view. Except in this case instead of showing a detail show another UItableview.